# How can I know how many packets a node forwards in Contiki?

Tags: contiki, rpl

When I set `UIP_STATISTICS=1`, I can use `uip_stat.udp.sent` to know how many UDP packets I have send, but it does not include the number of packets forwarded. So how can I get it?

Comment: Does `uip_stat.forwarded` work for you? There is no counter at the UDP level, because UDP does not forward any packets. UDP is an end-to-end protocol, the forwarding is done by IP.

Comment: Thanks, I can use uip_stat.ip.sent - uip_stat.udp.sent - uip_stat.icmp.sent to accept the number of packets forwarded. What do you think?